# MySQL Match() not finding most optimal match

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, match

I have a database of occupation titles I'm trying to run some queries on. I'm using Match() to try and find the best match occupational title for a user-entered string using this SQL:

```
SELECT *, MATCH (occupation_title) AGAINST ('EGG PROCESSOR') 
AS score FROM occupational_titles WHERE MATCH (occupation_title) 
AGAINST ('EGG PROCESSOR') ORDER BY score DESC;
```

When I run this query against my database, the first three results are "Processor", "Egg Processor", and "COPRA Processor". The first two have the exact same match score of 6.04861688613892. Why on earth would MySQL not rank an exact match hit as the number one result? Is there anything I can do to refine the search algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use one of the modifier modes in your searches.  Check the [fulltext documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match).

In particular, by default it uses "natural language" searching, while you probably want to consider "boolean mode" and prefixing each keyword with a plus sign to make it mandatory in results, or using double quotes to search for the exact phrase.  [Check the boolean mode documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) for more information on the syntax.

You can also consider performing multiple searches using a variety of modes and doing your own weighting.

Comment: I don't mind natural language for when I cant find an exact match, but it;s in cases like this that it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should change the collation of your Column to case insensitive ones.
eg. latin1 to latin1_bin

Case sensitive Match is being done in your case.
Have a look here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html